# Node.JS: Why do nested promise thens seem to run out of order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

I need each download and getFiles call to run separately because firebase seems unable to handle too many connections.

```
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName); // firebase storage bucket
var queue = Promise.resolve();

websiteNames.reduce(function(promise, websiteName) {
    return promise
    .then(() => {
        mkdirp(websiteName)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("now getting files: " + dirPath);
        return bucket.getFiles({prefix: dirPath})
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log("got files");
        var files = data[0];
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            var storePath = tmpDir + "/" + file.name;
            queue = queue
            .then(() => {
                console.log("now downloading: " + file.name);
                return file.download({destination: storePath});
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`downloaded to ${storePath}.`);
                return readFile(storePath, 'utf8');
            })
            .then(buffer => {
                console.log("readed file: " + storePath + " of buf size " + buffer.length);
            });
        });
    });
}, queue);
```

I expected that the big then block will be adding download actions to a queue which already has all the getFiles actions. So I expect it to make all the getFiles calls, before starting to download the files. But console logs like this:

```
now getting files: foo/a
got files
now downloading: foo/a/0.csv
now getting files: foo/b
got files
now getting files: foo/c
got files
downloaded to /tmp/foo/a/0.csv.
```

Why does foo/a/0.csv start downloading before all the bucket getFiles calls are made? Shouldn't the file download thens have been added to the end of the queue after it already had the getFiles thens? Moreover foo/a has multiple files, so why did only 1 file download sneak in between the getFiles calls?

Comment: You are missunderstanding Promises. You iterate over your website names and attach handlers to your promises. They will be executed asynchronously, whatever happens first.
There are js plugins for Promise queues though.

Answer (score 1):

The nested structure is the problem.
There is no mechanism to prevent the inner loop to promises to the queue, when all the outer ones aren't in the queue yet. As soon as you create the first Promise it will start to "work" and the handlers will be called, so if you aren't done with adding all the Promises, and the first Promise reaches the point where it adds Promises to the queue again, you get what your observed.

Your nested structure is what makes it impossible. Take a look at [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). First build a distinct Array with all the file download Promises.
Ask the Array when all the promises have resolved with Promise.all, then attach the `then` handler to your Promise.all with the inner loop.

Promise.all will have an array of all files, that you can use to perform more steps, by building another distinct queue.

Comment: I was unable to understand "but since you attach handlers to multiple promises" -- which handlers and where did I do it? Does it happen because the first websiteName mkdirp and getFiles finishes before the outermost reduce loop finishes running? Thus leading to a race condition? 

How would the queue example work with a forEach loop (the files need to be individually downloaded, after the file list is downloaded)?

Comment: @pete
I overlooked something in your code, but the promise queue still applies.
Consider following case.
You first attach all the handlers to A. Which right away start to work, parallel you are adding B, C 
Now handler A reaches the files.foreach block and Adds more events to the queue. A1, A2, A3
Then you add D, E, .. and so on.
The problem is there is nothing to stop the inner loop to add promises to your queue.

Comment: @pete I got it all wrong, but updatd my answer accordingly. Try it out if this doesn't help, mention me again and we'll figure it out.

Comment: @pete Have you figured it out yet?